# DataGridView C# windows application(First row not selecting which is checkbox if mouse click on column Header)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, checkbox, datagridview

Can please any one help me on this. I have developed a c# windows application which has DataGridView first column has checkboxes. if I click on first column header it selects all the row level check boxes except the first row. For selecting all row level check boxes I have an event of dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick and the code is:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            }
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                if (chek == 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
                        {
                            string paymentValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[18].Value.ToString();
                            string incmngp = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[20].Value.ToString();
                            if (paymentValue == "N" && incmngp =="")
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = 1;
                                chek = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        if (chek == 1)
                        {
                            btn_update.Text = "Update";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ) {  }
                }
                else if(chek==1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = 0;
                            chek = 0;
                        }
                        if (chek == 0)
                        {
                            btn_update.Text = "OK";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }
            }
```

**Note: chek is the variable declared on initialize stage**

Comment: Yes... we understand ....and your problem is?

Comment: @SurajS first row is not selecting if we click on column header. But from second to the end of the row all the checkboxes are selected not for the first row.

Comment: @SurajS Can you please provide a solution for this. Not selecting the first row after modifying the code like which you have given. http://i.imgur.com/WihxVvK.png

Comment: @SurajS Many thanks. I just added .RefreshEdit() at below of my code its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your Selection mode property of data grid view to **ColumnHeaderSelect**

[image]

and make sure all your 'Text' columns have *SortMode* set to **NotSortable**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

In which case, **Undo** everything I ever told before and do that like this

Before you are assigning any DataTable to dataGridView1.

```
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
     foreach(DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    dc.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
                }
 dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
```

**UPDATE 3**

Add an event handler for your dataGridView1's **ColumnHeaderMouseClick** Event
like below

[image]

Add the below code (Generic code if you want to use the same functionality for any column of check boxes)

```
 private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Enter your own column index here
            if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                    //Check if the cell type is of a CheckBoxCell
                if (cell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell c = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)cell;
                    c.TrueValue = "T";
                    c.FalseValue = "F";
                    if (c.Value == c.FalseValue|| c.Value == null )
                    c.Value = c.TrueValue;
                    else
                        c.Value = c.FalseValue;
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for helping. Did same like you suggest above for Selection Mode. but throwing an error of **Column's SortMode  cannot be set to Automatic while the DataGridView control's SelectionMode is set to ColumnHeaderSelect**

Comment: @Naveen.A Updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this issue. Still there is no luck on this first row is not selecting if click on column header. Image for your reference http://i.imgur.com/WihxVvK.png

Comment: can you please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Many Thanks... I just added datagridview1.RefreshEdit() below of my code its working fine now

Comment: Please accept the answer to close it! if your issue is resolved! @Naveen.A

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bizarre bug in Winforms. The problem more generally applies not to the first row, but to the first selected cell in any row of DataGridViewCheckBoxCell(s). You can select the CheckBox cell by clicking on the check box, or select the cell outside the check box, the behavior is the same. If you select 3 check boxes in the middle of your grid, the first of those three will freeze and not update properly. If you try to clear the selection in code, with a dataGridView1.ClearSelection() method call, it still does not work.

The correct answer is to call datagridview1.RefreshEdit() right after you change the checkbox data. You can't just call it after all changes are made. It must be made for each change in the CheckBox value.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Results.Rows)
    {
       var ck =  (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) row.Cells["check"];
       ck.Value = ck.TrueValue;
       Results.RefreshEdit();
     }
```